# Full width image strategy

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I wanted to present the user with a screen shot of my app while it's in use, and then create a black overlay on it, and then create coach marks on the screen, similar to something like this, when the user first registers:

[image]

So I created the image and I want to make sure that no matter who uses it, it always fits nicely on their iphone4/iphone5/ipad mini/ipad, etc. What is the best approach to do this these days? Just take one giant image (make it like  1297 x 2208), add this to my asset catalog for all 3 sizes, and then just have autolayout resize it for me normally? I.e. put an imageview on the page, set it to always take up the entire screen width, and then set it's image to my giant image? Would it always resize down and look good?

Another thought that popped into my head is create lots of different images, then use all of the size classes to make the image (seems like a lot of tedious work for just a full page image so thinking this is the wrong approach).

What's the right strategy for creating a giant image that always fits? is it to go really high, and have it resize, or is it to create lots of images with different dimensions, and somehow detect which to use?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't take a screenshot of your image, just let the real UI show through. This lets you have some future changes to the UI w/o having to redo your "screenshotted" UI.

I'd also make different help images for each screensize, it isn't that much work and it lets you not squish or stretch your overlay.

I've also code up, but can't share the code,  for a three part approach, top, middle and bottom, this way I could handle the 3.5" and 4" devices easily without stretching.

Comment: H Paul thanks for your reply. With your approach, I would have to find specific elements and overlay images to float above them to create the effect? What was your strategy for doing it? Something similar? In truth I prefer the way I was going over this because when the first screen starts, I have a lot of bootstrapping events fire off, a dialog box appearing to welcome the new user, etc, and i'd have to suppress all of that until the user dismisses the overlay but I guess I can do that if you recommend it. Maybe i'm being lazy, too :)

Comment: I had a gray translucent overlay that stretched for the "middle" components, then a non-stretching top and bottom that had the white  lettering on it. (We only had top and bottom ui widgets.) Note, you'll not, if I remember correctly, be able to push a view controller since I think I tried that and couldn't make the background clear. Use a container view controller and you'll be all set.

Comment: Oh, just reread your first comment, I just used 3 big graphics, not a per ui element. Download the Vivoom app and take it apart, you'll see how I did it.

Comment: And yeah, the welcome dialogs need to be delayed, otherwise it is ugly, lots of code but a good UX is worth it.